# Inserting a node with a value depending on the value of its sibling

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, copy

This is an example, I want to know if it's possible.

I have some xml which I want to loop through  and check the value of  Depending on this value I want to insert a value in .

How I essentially want it work is:
if node1 = aa or ab
node0 = awesome
and
if node1 = bc or bd
node0 = beautiful

However I only want node0 to display beautiful or awesome the in the first node0 from the set.

This is the input

```
<parent>
    <sibling>
        <node1>aa</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node1>ab</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
     </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node1>bb</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node1>bc</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node1>bd</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
</parent>
```

The output

```
<parent>
    <sibling>
        <node0>awesome</node0>
        <node1>aa</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node0></node0>
        <node1>ab</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node0>beautiful</node0>
        <node1>bb</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node0></node0>
        <node1>bc</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
    <sibling>
        <node0></node0>
        <node1>bd</node1>
        <node2></node2>
        <node3></node3>
        <node4></node4>
        <node5></node5>
    </sibling>
</parent>
```

Comment: Your example does not match your rules, I think. Also, what exactly do you mean by "the first time"/

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited. What I mean is when there is a group of 3 siblings which have for example bb in the first bb in the second and bd in the last. a node0 with the value beautiful appears in only the first sibling. And the other two have a blank node0

Comment: Okay, but that's still ambiguous because it could mean either the first of every contiguous group or first overall (which is what my solution below does).

Comment: Yes it depends on the group, hence why I put two node0's with a value. I could use two xslt. The first to go through to input awesome then another to input beautiful??

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite follow. Have you examined the answer I have posted? If it doesn't do what you're looking for, please add a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sibling[node1='aa' or node1='ab'][1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <node0>awesome</node0>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sibling[node1='bb' or node1='bc'][1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <node0>beautiful</node0>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sibling">
    <xsl:copy>
        <node0/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Useful tip for inserting <node0/> like elements within xsl:copy.

Comment: Sorry, this works perfectly. Could you explain what each part does so I can emulate in the future?

Comment: The first template is an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) rule. The other three are exceptions to the rule, and they are self-explanatory, I think.